# Why can't [std::unique] apply to [std::multiset]?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, standards

```
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
        multiset<int> coll{ 1, 1, 2 };
        unique(coll.begin(), coll.end()); // error
}
```

Why can't `std::unique` apply to `std::multiset`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because [std::unique](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) changes (by shifting) the elements in the range [first, last) passed in by move assignment. That means it requires the type of dereferenced iterator must meet the requirements of MoveAssignable.

> Type requirements
>
> - ForwardIt must meet the requirements of [ForwardIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/ForwardIterator).
> - The type of dereferenced ForwardIt must meet the requirements of [MoveAssignable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/MoveAssignable).

But the iterator of [std::multiset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) is const iterator (since C++11), which doesn't meet the requirement. The deferenced element can't be move assigned via them.

Comment: I'm looking [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset) and pre-C++11 `iterator` was not constant. How did that work?

Comment: @LogicStuff pre-c++11 the order of the elements could be changed, therefore you could apply `std::unique`

Comment: @LogicStuff If my memory is correct, pre C++11 the standard is not clear enough about that; some implmentations allow it, some not.

Answer (score 3):

`std::multiset` is internaly sorted container, `std::unique` is changing elements possitions in container. `std::unique` is using `container::iterator_type` in it's implementations and due to the fact that structure of `std::multiset` is strict, it has only `const_iterator_type`. Therefore `std::unique` cannot be applied on `std::multiset` type.

Before c++11 was introduced internal structure of `std::multimap` could be changed, so `std::unique` could be applied on such container.

Answer (score 2):

[`std::unique`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) doesn't remove repeating values from the range. Instead it moves them to the end of the range (by swapping two elements in the input sequence). In `std::multiset` and other associative containers the order of the elements is defined by the sorting predicate and cannot be altered by the user. This restriction is achieved by making the non-const iterator of `std::multiset` somewhat similar to its `const_iterator` (i.e. you cannot modify an element of a `std::multiset` through its non-const iterator).